# Apache .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess :

`

```
php_value error_reporting 6135
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|inc|sh|pl|log|fla)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

`

so it rewrite any file not found to /index.php.

how could i do to don't rewrite jpg, gif, css and some other special extension, because it hapens that if i try to link ti a css file that doesn't exist, it open the index.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This one should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*$(?<!\.(css|jpg|gif)) index.php [L,R]
```

All extensions must be sparated by `|`.

Comment: now, it act a kind of a redirect and on url it shows /var/www/../index.php